# How this numpy advance indexing code works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-indexing, advanced-indexing

I am learning numpy framework.This piece of code I don't understand.

```
import numpy as np
a =np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
print(a)
row = np.array([[0,0],[3,3]])
col = np.array([[0,2],[0,2]])
b = a[row,col]
print("This is b array:",b)
```

This `b` array returns the corner values of `a` array, that is, `b`  equals `[[0,2],[9,11]]`.

Comment: You're saying you don't understand the code, please be more specific. What are you trying to do? What don't you understand? Please read this before asking a question: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're indexing `a` using two equally shaped `2d-arrays`, hence you're output array will also have the same shape as `col` and `row`. To better understand how `array indexing` works you can check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), where as shown, indexing with `1d-arrays` over the existing axis' of a given array works as follows:

> result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M],
>                              ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]

Where the same logic applies in the case of indexing with `2d-arrays` over each axis, but instead you'd have a `result` array with up to `i_N_M` indices.

So going back to your example you are essentially selecting from the rows of `a` based on `row`, and from those `rows` you are selecting some columns `col`. You might find it more intuitive to translate the row and column indices into `(x,y)` coordinates:

```
(0,0), (0,2)   
(3,0), (3,2)
```

Which, by accordingly selecting from `a`, results in the output array:

```
print(a[row,col])

array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Answer (score 4):

When indexing is done using an array or "array-like", to access/modify the elements of an array, then it's called advanced indexing.

```
In [37]: a
Out[37]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

In [38]: row
Out[38]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [3, 3]])

In [39]: col
Out[39]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 2]])

In [40]: a[row, col]
Out[40]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

That's what you got. Below is an explanation:

```
              Indices of  
`a[row, col]` row  column  
   ||   ||    ||   ||
   VV   VV    VV   VV
  a[0,  0]   a[0,  2]   
  a[3,  0]   a[3,  2]
    |__________|   |
   row-idx array   |
        |__________| 
        column-idx array
```

Comment: Your visual presentation is stunning, can you tell me how you did it? With tools or completely manual typesetting?

Answer (score 0):

You can understand it by making more tries, to see more examples.

If you have one dimensional index:

```
In [58]: np.arange(10)[np.array([1,3,4,6])]
Out[58]: array([1, 3, 4, 6])
```

In case of two dimensional index:

```
In [57]: np.arange(10)[np.array([[1,3],[4,6]])]
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [4, 6]])
```

If you use 3 dimensional index:

```
In [59]: np.arange(10)[np.array([[[1],[3]],[[4],[6]]])]
Out[59]: 
array([[[1],
        [3]],

       [[4],
        [6]]])
```

As you can see, if you make hierarchy in indexing, you will get it in the output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding by steps:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])

print(a)
```

gives 2d array `a`:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Then:

```
row = np.array([[0,0],[3,3]])
```

assigns to 2d array `row` values `[0,0]` and `[3,3]`:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [3, 3]])
```

Then:

```
col = np.array([[0,2],[0,2]])
```

assigns to 2d array `col` values `[0,2]` and `[0,2]`:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 2]])
```

Finally:

```
b = a[row,col]
```

assigns to `b` values given by `a[0,0]`, `a[0,2]` for the first row, `a[3,0]`, `a[3,2]` for the second row, that is:

```
 array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Where does `b[0,0]` <-- `a[0,0]` come from? It comes from the combination of `row[0,0]` which is 0 and `col[0,0]` which is 0.

What about `b[0,1]` <-- `a[0,2]`? It comes from the combination of `row[0,1]` which is 0 and `col[0,1]` which is 2.

And so forth.